# Most parallel algorithm for calculating sum of squares?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing

Say I need to calculate the sum of squares for a big array A[n] where n could be millions and I have N threads to use. Can anyone point me to a good parallel algorithm for doing this? thanks!

Comment: Divide the array into chunks of size `n / N` and then process one chunk per thread ?

Comment: This seems like an embarrassingly parallel problem.  I don't think there's anything significantly better than just splitting the array into `N` parts and letting each thread compute their sums of squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algorithm :-

```
1. divide numbers in n/N blocks 
2. Compute for one block squares in parallel in O(1)
3. addition can be done in O(log(N)) for 1 block using adding pair at time
```

Time complexity :-
 **O(log(N)*(n/N))**

**Note:** This time complexity is completely theorical practically you need to wait for threads to sync after end of parallel operation which increases delay.

Edit:-

Following pseudo code might explain `O(logN)` parallel algorithm for a thread :-

```
void add(i,N) {

  int k = 1;

  while(i+k<N && i%k==0 && (i/k)%2==0) {

      arr[i] = arr[i]+arr[i+k];
      synchronize();
      k = 2*k;
   }


}
```

**Note :-** This is code for thread number i working on `ith` index of N sized block , note that the loop is **O(logN)** as k increases by 2 times every iteration , **synchronize()** function is used to wait for other threads to finish their iteration if they are not in sync. Try to solve this for an example you will get the idea , the final answer of addition will be in `arr[0]`

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "adding pair" piece? I think that's really what I am not clear about. Is that just simply adding things one by one serially? Sorry I should have mentioned it earlier in my original post. thanks

Comment: Take a look at reduction algorithms, they are the way to parallelize large sums, instead of adding one by one serially. You can look [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/parallel-pattern-7-reduce/222000718) to get an idea of what a reduction is. Several parallel reduction algorithms can be found online.

Comment: @user2210021 check my edit , written a pseudo code hope it helps you understand the concept